# AsyncTask or not? Server synchronisation activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am looking for best practice with this question.

Basically, I have an application with "start up" activity before going into the main activity. The user can not do anything at all, as the application needs to first ynchronise with the server by throwing some HTTP requests.

The easiest route would be to run in sequence on the UI thread each HTTP request. Is there any particular issues with this? (ie processing Android framework would normally do that is blocked?, ...). I d like implementing this with the first version, and refine later with the appraoch listed below.

Otherwise, from a user perspective, is it better to initiate one AsyncTask per HTTP requests concurrently, and synchronise in the UI thread when I can launch the next activity.

Cheers.
l_ingenu

Answer (score 1):

Use `AsyncTask` to do your HTTP calls stuff, because starting from Honeycomb, it is not allowed to use internet operations on UI thread (unless you change the policy).

Once your calls are finished, return the desired result to `onPostExecute` and decide whether you want to continue with the next `Activity` or throw an error to the user.

Comment: it's allowed (still, it can result in ANR), but with default policy such approach will throw an exception. You, however, can enable this if you really need.

Comment: If your API level is below **11**, then it will cause ANR, otherwise with default policy, it will throw `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception. Read [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting you to **not** use AsyncTask, instead use [IntentService](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/) :)

Comment: IntentService's jobs are queued. It's not always acceptable behaviour.

Comment: AsyncTask from Android ICS (4.0) AsyncTask are serialized (queued) too and this will break your logic. Also IntentService allow you to continue your network work also when app is in background and when user change orientation / change activity. Look here for more informazion about AsyncTask regression: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html

Comment: AsyncTask serialization can be easily solved by using `executeOnExecutor()`. Changing orientation is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First things first 

you have to use a separate thread using UI thread for network activity it's a good practice 

[http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html][1]

Secondly you need to make a choice here:

if your entire application is dependent on the data from server and has to be fetched before showing content in your application you should use AsyncTask and move to next Activity in onPostExecute().

if you are using the data in your application and it doesn't have so much affect in the first screen users are viewing use Services.